# Can I seed a mongodb docker container from an other docker container without docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Can I seed an running mongodb container from an other container?
I can do it with docker-compose, but that means it gets seeded every time I start it up and will create duplicate data in my database.

This is part of my compose file:

```
version: '5.2' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
  database: # My database
    image: mongo # specify image to build container from
    ports:
      - "27017:27017" # specify port forewarding
```

Dockerfile I want to use to seed

```
FROM mongo

COPY init.json /init.json
CMD mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 --port=27017 --db mean-docker --collection authusers --type json --file /init.json --jsonArray
```

init.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "pass": "bar"
  },
  {
    "name": "foo2",
    "pass": "bar2"
  }
]
```

With this setup I am getting a:

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to container from another container they should be in common network.

Docker-compose create common network for all services.

To connect new container to existing network you can use 
[docker network connect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/)

May be better option to seed your db will be use [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command like this:

```
docker exec [OPTIONS] existing_container_with_mongodb mongoimport [your_args]
```

Comment: The command line solution seems like the best way to go thanks! But I am now getting a "Failed: open init.json: no such file or directory"

Comment: @H.Hakvoort yes, you should put file into container or pass data from this file as command line argument. To put file you cant either link folder into mongodb container where you will store such files or use [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)